# Javascript return data with promise

Tags: javascript

How do I return data with promise? my below code works fine but when I switch this to promise, it does not return any data.

```
export function userSignupRequest(username, password) {

  return (dispatch) => {
    if (username === 'hello@world.com' && password === 'admin') {
       console.log('Sign up success')
       dispatch(setLoginSuccess(true));
       return userAccountDataFromSever
     } else {
       console.log('Sing up failed')
       return new Error('Will be an error message from server')
     }    
  }
}
```

I get either `userAccountDataFromSever` or `new Error('Will be an error message from server')` from above code by `console.log(userSignupRequest(email, password))` However, when I switched this to below, it returned `undefined`.

```
export function userSignupRequest(username, password) {

  return (dispatch) => {
    Auth.signUp({
        username,
        password
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      dispatch(setLoginSuccess(true));
      return data;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return new Error(err.message)
    });

  }
}
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: You should be using promises

Comment: I'd suggest you to do some reading on promises. They're pretty fundamental in javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! yes, I really need to do some readings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `userSignupRequest` will do **asynchronous operations**, it becomes an asynchronous function.

The current way to 'return' values in async function is returning a promise and then using the .then().catch() syntax.

Example of your function returning a promise:

```
export function userSignupRequest(username, password) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Auth.signUp({
          username,
          password
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        dispatch(setLoginSuccess(true));
        return resolve(data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        return reject(err);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Example of use:

```
userSignupRequest('admin', 'admin')(dispatch)
  .then(user => console.log(`User ${user} signed up!`)
  .catch(err => console.error(err);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Helped me a lot!